# How can I reference and use .NET Core 3.0 and .NET EF 4.7 projects, in a third project, and use their database connections?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core-3.0

I'm mainly PHP dev, recently forced into .NET.

I have a solution with 2 projects:

1. one has data connection to one database and is a .NET Core project
2. another one has data connection to a second database and it is .NET EF 4.7 project.

I want to create a console app that will allow me to work with both databases. I need those 2 projects as they already have all models and connection defined and work well on their own. I need to be able to connect to both databases, and fetch some data to output in a console.

So far I've created a third project, Core 3.0. I managed to use the 1st project data connection, but I can't possibly work out how to use the EF 4.7 project connection. I'm getting this error:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is
>   either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.  --->
>   System.ArgumentException: The specified invariant name
>   'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET
>   Data Providers.

I've tried reinstalling EntityFramework, checked app.config (provider string is there), checked if `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` is in dependencies - everything seems ok.

Is this even possible? Can the 3rd project be a Core 3.0 project? Someone mentioned that I should use .NET Standard Class Library to work with both projects, but Class library is not a console app. Please point me in the right direction...

Comment: can you please show your app.config

Comment: @Varin: Both 1 and 2 should be .NET Standard projects. The third should target either .NET Core or the .NET Framework.

Comment: @mm8 The problem is that 1 and 2 are already existing Core and Framework projects - all I need to do is to be able to use them both (data connection, models) in a third projects that will eventually be a data import project.

Comment: @Varin: You can't "use" a .NET Core project from a .NET Framework project and vice versa. That's why there is the .NET Standard.

Comment: .net core 3.0 uses .net standard 2.1, which .classic .net framework 4.x versions can't consume. You can only target .net standard 2.0 and use this shared code in both, core and classic framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 should be .NET Standard projects. The third should target either .NET Core or the .NET Framework.

I am afraid you can't "use" a .NET Core project from a .NET Framework project and vice versa. That's why there is the .NET Standard.

You may want to consider breaking out parts of your existing projects into class libraries that target .NET Standard. You can then reference them from any app that is compiled against a version that is compatible with the .NET Standard version you are targeting.

Comment: Does this mean that it is completely impossible to have .NET Core project and a .NET framework project and talk to them (use them) in another .NET Core project? Do I always have to use .NET Standard Class Library to "talk to" those projects? What about the output? .NET Standard does not have a "Console App" option - what can be done in this case?

Comment: Yes. A .NET Core project can only reference another .NET Core project or a .NET Standard project. Same thing with a .NET Framework project. It can only target another .NET Framework project or a .NET Standard project. .NET Core and the .NET Framework are two different runtimes. .NET Standard is [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) of APIs. That's why there is so thing as a .NET Standard "app" because an app requires a runtime to execute.

Comment: So technically I could have a .NET Core console app referencing another .NET Core project AND a .NET Standard project? In this case, I could convert the 1st .NET Framework project to Standard, leave 2nd as is (.NET Core) and create 3rd  project (.NET Core) which references the 1st and 2nd? Is that correct?